# OpenFileDialog->Filter in windows form application in C++ does not work

Tags: c++, filter, openfiledialog

in my windows form project, in C++ , visual 2010, I'm using this line with this purpose that user just select this types of files:

```
openFileDialog1->Filter =  "Image Files(*.png, *.jpg)|*.png;*.jpg";
```

this line is written before openfiledialog1->ShowDialog();

but when I run the project and open the OpenFileDialog, I can see files in other format, such as *.txt.

where is my fault?

thank you so much ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for what you are trying to do is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea

The string needs to be formatted using nulls as delimiters for the different sections of a filter. So, your string should be formatted as follows:

```
openFileDialog1->Filter =  "Image Files (*.png, *.jpg)\0*.png;*.jpg\0";
```

Comment: Hi Peter; thank u for your help : but in your answer the backslashes must change into '|' ; otherwise the project face with an unhandled exception error :-) so the correct format is :
openFileDialog1->Filter =  "Image Files (*.png, *.jpg)|0*.png;*.jpg";

Answer (score 0):

Probably the comma should be a semicolon. Maybe the space (after that comma) is not allowed either.