# How to Run File Explorer From C++ Program and Show Only Certain Files on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, microsoft-file-explorer

I'm sorry if this question sounds a bit vague. I am making a windows 11 application in C++, and I am making an editor where I want there to be an option to upload a file of a certain type. Let's say there is a button to upload a file type; I want the file explorer to open with only the files of the chosen type to be showing.

Is it possible to do this directly from my C++ program, or will I have to make own process for using the file explorer in this way?

Comment: it's too broad. Which GUI framework are you using? WPF? MFC? WinForms? WinUI?... In any case you need to look up the way to filter the browse file dialog: [OpenFileDialog->Filter in windows form application in C++ does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18312745/995714)

Comment: @phuclv I'm not using any GUI framework, except for SDL if that counts.

Comment: how can you show a GUI without a GUI framework? Yes you can call Win32 APIs directly but it's not something easy to learn

Comment: @phuclv You're probably right that I should be using a Windows GUI for this.  However, this is the only part of my program that I intend to interact with windows at all, so I thought I could get away with this one process.

Comment: I do not think you need a whole framework for this as phuclv suggests, there are simple API calls just for this, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog) has all you need, it includes the full C++ code and filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic open dialog allows you to filter by file extension(s):

```
WCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
OPENFILENAME ofn = {};
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
//ofn.hwndOwner = ...;
ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("Only text and log files\0*.TXT;*.LOG\0");
ofn.lpstrFile = buffer, ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH, *buffer = '\0';
ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER|OFN_ENABLESIZING|OFN_HIDEREADONLY|OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST|OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)) DoSomethingWithFile(ofn.lpstrFile);
```

Note: An advanced user can type `*` in the file name field to bypass this filter. You would think `OFN_ENABLEINCLUDENOTIFY` would give you more control but it does not let you filter filesystem items. MSDN is going to recommend that you use the newer Vista IFileDialog but MSDN also says about `IFileDialog::SetFilter`:

> Deprecated. SetFilter is no longer available for use as of Windows 7

(In my testing it does seem to work however (tested Windows 8 and 10)).

`IFileDialog` supports the same basic extension filter as `GetOpenFileName` but unless you need to support non-filesystem items and intend to implement everything in terms of `IStream`, it is just extra work.

Comment: "*Note: An advanced user can type `*` in the file name field to bypass this filter.*" - true, but you can validate the selected file(s) in a [`CDN_FILEOK` notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/cdn-fileok) before the dialog is allowed to close.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point. But all of this is pointless, the user can just rename their file to pass the check. The extension filter should be enough for most cases.

Comment: "*the user can just rename their file to pass the check*" - sure, unless the `CDN_FILEOK` handler is coded to open the file(s) to validate their content(s).